# Flutter : How to get an index from a list by searching from a value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list:

```
List user = [
{"name": "Alex", "id": "001"}, 
{"name": "Brandon", "id": "002"}, 
{"name": "Charlie", "id": "003"}, 
{"name": "Danny", "id": "004"},
];
```

and I have a variable with value

```
String a = "002";
int index;
```

My question is how to get an index value from a list of `user` while I do a search by passing a value from `a` ?

So I'll have an `index = 1`

Thank you :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```dart
 int index = user.indexWhere((item) => item["id"] == a);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to search in respect to any value in Map then you can do the following.

```
int index = user.indexWhere((item) => item.containsValue(a));
```